# Exrin tabbed view: navigation between tabs using NavigationResult

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage, exrin

In my Exrin-based app I have a tabbed view. As an operation execution result I would like to select a specific tab. But when I pass the NavigationResult(Stacks.TabStack, TabStack.RootViewKey) as an operation result, the tabs selection is kept as it was before operation.
Should I use another NavigationResult c-tor or adapt the TabbedView container somehow?

Comment: Selecting a tab, based on Stack isn't actually implemented, it's been on my todo list :) I'll have a look at it tonight and see how much it will take to implement this feature.

Comment: @AdamPedley ok, thank you :)